# Vanilla Javascript and Ajax - $_POST is empty

Tags: javascript, ajax

I send data with ajax using the POST method.

Once the data are sent $_POST['my_value'] remains empty.

However the expected value is in $_GET['my_value'].

Here is my ajax call:

```
loadAjaxDoc( 'https://www.mypage.com/?my_value=test', 1000, initGame );

function loadAjaxDoc( url, timeout, cFunction ) {

    var xhr;

    setTimeout(function() {

        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

            elements.interludeCountdownDiv.innerHTML = '[[%doodles.game_loaded]]';

            if ( this.readyState == 4 ) { 

                elements.interludeCountdownDiv.innerHTML = '[[%doodles.game_loading_state4]]';

                if ( this.status === 0 || ( this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400 ) ) {

                    if ( this.status == 200 ) {

                        cFunction( this );

                    }

                }

            }

        };

        xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
        xhr.timeout = timeout;

        setTimeout( function() {

            xhr.send( null );

        }, 1000 );

    }, 1000 );

}
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Can someone give a hand for this? Any help appreciated :)

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? It would be simpler to read your code if you removed all parts that are not relevant

Comment: You're passing a GET parameter in a POST URL.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it - don't put releant information in the comment section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP superglobals `$_POST` and `$_GET` are not directly related to the HTTP request method.

`$_GET` is populated with data from the URL's query string.

`$_POST` is populated with data from the request body (if it uses a supported encoding like `application/www-url-encoded`).

We can't see what URL you are passing, but since you say the data is showing up in `$_GET` you must have put the data there.

We can see what you put in the request body — `null` — so the body will be empty.

---

If you want to populate the body you could do something like:

```
const body = new FormData();
body.append('my_value', "some value");
xhr.send(body);
```